# Isolated web app under wwwroot subdirectory by web.config only

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis, web-config

Given FTP access to `wwwroot` dir only (that already has a working web app, accessible by `http://somedomain.com/`) how can I define another web app in `wwwroot/new` dir (accessible by `http://somedomain.com/new/`), that will use DLLs from `wwwroot/new/bin` and not from `wwwroot/bin`? No access to IIS.

tnx a lot